# typescript return data object from external source

Tags: javascript, typescript

is there anything wrong with my typescript code below?

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const createOrder = async (
  locale: string
): Promise<any | null> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      url,
      {data: locale}
    );
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return null;
  }
};
```

some argued that Promise<any | null> is bad practice, but I wonder what's wrong with that here since we don't have clue about the structure of the data as it's coming from external source.

Comment: You can use `unknown` instead of `any`, which forces you to assert the type once you're trying to use the data

Comment: @MikeS. imagine you have to define every single property type defined by someone else, not all data is relevant to your use, isn't it overkill need to deny the return type in api calls?

Comment: You can define only the props you're actually using/ accessing. What do you do with the response afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to ask is:

Can you trust what's coming from the API? Do you believe it will remain consistent? If not, what could the effects/risks are?

Some people believe that when you interact with (especially a 3rd party-) API, you should always validate everything it returns. I think that's not always true, and a balance you need to strike.

If you intent to fully validate what's coming back from the API, use `unknown`, not `any` and figure out if you got what you expected with type guards and assertion functions.

Comment: what's the best or at least common practice for this? in real life we make api calls to bunch of things, include stuff like analytic and tracking, I don't see the point.

Comment: No, because it is situation dependent. Try to assess the risk and impact of an API returning unexpected, and go from there. If you think the likelihood is low, or it's not worth the time validating responses, then don't.